# Parsing a text Java

Tags: java, parsing, bufferedreader, stringbuffer

How can i reach this text from text file with Java? Here is my text, from which i need parse text..

```
SHA256: 0cd6fb0d5d40fe5628b930f7705952f4041384ebc198d67c857606cf83d79f45
File type: advanced_disk_cleaner.exe
Detection ratio: 0 / 55
Number of sections  8
? PE sections
Name  Virtual address  Virtual size  Raw size  Entropy  MD5
CODE  4096  37732  37888  6.56  2c410dfc3efd04d9b69c35c70921424e
DATA  45056  588  1024  2.74  d5ea23d4ecf110fd2591314cbaa84278
BSS  49152  3720  0  0.00  d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
.idata  53248  2384  2560  4.43  bb5485bf968b970e5ea81292af2acdba
.tls  57344  8  0  0.00  d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
.rdata  61440  24  512  0.20  9ba824905bf9c7922b6fc87a38b74366
.reloc  65536  2228  0  0.00  d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
.rsrc  69632  378360  378368  4.42  dc75e95cd49ce06a635cad0b18dab6d7
? Overlays
 MD5  396cf38f7077aeeb81871b8192ab4ea1
File type  data
Offset  421376
Size  2307072
Entropy  8.00
? PE imports
[+] advapi32.dll ()
LookupPrivilegeValueA
RegCloseKey
OpenProcessToken
RegQueryValueExA
AdjustTokenPrivileges
RegOpenKeyExA
```

Java Code...

```
String fileName = "c://lines.txt";

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
      //  System.out.println(line); 
        String[] split=line.split(" "); s
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I need get text, which is marked with **, rows with MD5, type, offset, size, entropy..this 5 rows, in which are overlays decribed.
Thanks Guys.

Comment: See this - the 2nd example:  http://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-stream-read-a-file-line-by-line/

Comment: I don't see any text marked with **. Is it possible ** turned into bold text or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if(line.startsWith("MD5") || line.startsWith("<Other Tags>"))
 {
   String[] split=line.split(" ");
 }
```

and print the splitted string and see where is MD5 and the other contents.

Comment: Updated the answer, please use OR conditions to search for other tags. Replace <Other Tags> with appropriate start strings.

Comment: there is no option to start stringbuffer.append in row with Overlays and  stop over the row PE Imports? This can be best solution i think..but i dont know how to

Comment: I really dont get you. The above suggested solution in answer would work for you. All you have to do is StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer() before the while loop. and do bb.append inside the if condition.